# Cannot import and use postcss-simple-vars as a function

Tags: javascript, css, plugins, gulp, postcss

I am updating a PostCSS plugin to use PostCSS 8, and I am struggling with this error:

```
TypeError: vars(...) is not a function
```

The plugin is referenced in the code like so:

```
var vars = require('postcss-simple-vars');

...

vars({ only: value })(content);
```

The plugin was able to make this call before I updated the packages for it, but I'm not sure which one is breaking it. I've tried looking at the source code for [`postcss-simple-vars`](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-simple-vars) but I'm not understanding how this call isn't working.

These are the dependencies **BEFORE** upgrading:

```
"dependencies": {
    "postcss": "^5.0.0",
    "postcss-simple-vars": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "chai": "3.2.0",
    "gulp": "3.9.0",
    "gulp-eslint": "0.11.1",
    "gulp-mocha": "2.1.3",
    "postcss-custom-properties": "^5.0.1"
  }
```

**AFTER** updating packages:

```
"dependencies": {
    "postcss-simple-vars": "^6.0.3"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "postcss": "^8.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "chai": "4.3.6",
    "gulp": "4.0.2",
    "gulp-eslint": "6.0.0",
    "gulp-mocha": "8.0.0",
    "postcss": "^8.0.0",
    "postcss-custom-properties": "^12.1.8"
  }
```

The issue seems to be that `postcss-simple-vars` isn't importing as a function anymore, but I don't know *why*.

**UPDATE**

I managed to get it to at least partially compile using this invocation:

```
 const {root} = postcss([vars({ only: value })]).process(content)
```

My issue with this is that it kind of goes against the principles of PostCSS 8. They mention in their migration guide that you really shouldn't have to import the `postcss` package anymore to perform operations in a plugin. Though this is technically performing an operation using a separate plugin, it still feels like it could potentially cause performance issues. I don't think I'm smart enough to know how or why though.

Comment: I may be reading the so-called documentation wrong, but it seems you should be requiring it like `var vars = require('postcss-simple-vars')();`

Comment: This slightly changed the error but did not fix the issue:

`TypeError: vars is not a function`

Now it's not showing the `(...)` part but that's about it.

Comment: oh, wait, I didn't read your code correctly :p you are doing `vars({ only: value })(content);` so that's kind of the same as what I thought